# Why can't I run my tensorflow CNN model on this single image?

Tags: python, html, tensorflow, keras

I created a TensorFlow CNN from scratch to identify certain types of animals. I believe the model is working because I am getting data about the training data and I see a new folder in my directory when I run the code. When I try to run the code to predict it for a new single image, which is right below, I get this error. I'm new to TensorFlow, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The image is in the main directory and is a .jpg image. Let me know if you need more information. Thanks

```
CATEGORIES = ["cane", "cavallo", "elefante", "farfalla", "gallina",
      "gatto", "mucca", "pecora", "ragno", "scoiattolo"]
def prepare(file):
IMG_SIZE = 50
img_array = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("CNN.model")
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from skimage import transform
image = load('test.jpg')
model.predict(image)
prediction = model.predict([image])
prediction = list(prediction[0])
print(CATEGORIES[prediction.index(max(prediction))])
```

This is the error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-4-5c3fc0a5d50b> in <module>
     14 from skimage import transform
     15 image = load('test.jpg')
---> 16 model.predict(image)
     17 prediction = model.predict([image])
     18 prediction = list(prediction[0])

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     86       raise ValueError('{} is not supported in multi-worker mode.'.format(
     87           method.__name__))
---> 88     return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     89 
     90   return tf_decorator.make_decorator(

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1266           for step in data_handler.steps():
   1267             callbacks.on_predict_batch_begin(step)
-> 1268             tmp_batch_outputs = predict_function(iterator)
   1269             # Catch OutOfRangeError for Datasets of unknown size.
   1270             # This blocks until the batch has finished executing.

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    578         xla_context.Exit()
    579     else:
--> 580       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    581 
    582     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    625       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    626       initializers = []
--> 627       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    628     finally:
    629       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    504     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    505         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 506             *args, **kwds))
    507 
    508     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2444       args, kwargs = None, None
   2445     with self._lock:
-> 2446       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2447     return graph_function
   2448 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   2775 
   2776       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 2777       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   2778       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   2779       return graph_function, args, kwargs

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   2665             arg_names=arg_names,
   2666             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 2667             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   2668         self._function_attributes,
   2669         # Tell the ConcreteFunction to clean up its graph once it goes out of

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    979         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    980 
--> 981       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    982 
    983       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    439         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    440         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 441         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    442     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    443 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    966           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    967             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 968               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    969             else:
    970               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /Users/rin/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1147 predict_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    /Users/ron/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /Users/rn/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /Users/romin/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /Users/rin/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1122 predict_step  **
        return self(x, training=False)
    /Users/rn/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:886 __call__
        self.name)
    /Users/rkin/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:216 assert_input_compatibility
        ' but received input with shape ' + str(shape))

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_10 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape [None, 256, 256, 3]
```

This is code for the rest of the model:

```
file_list = []
class_list = []

DATADIR = "data"

# All the categories you want your elefante network to detect
CATEGORIES = ["cane", "cavallo", "elefante", "farfalla", "gallina",
          "gatto", "mucca", "pecora", "ragno", "scoiattolo"]

# The size of the images that your neural network will use
IMG_SIZE = 50

# Checking or all images in the data folder
for category in CATEGORIES :
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

training_data = []

def create_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES :
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try :
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass

create_training_data()

random.shuffle(training_data)

X = [] #features
y = [] #labels

for features, label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

# Creating the files containing all the information about your model
pickle_out = open("X.pickle", "wb")
pickle.dump(X, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()

pickle_out = open("y.pickle", "wb")
pickle.dump(y, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()

pickle_in = open("X.pickle", "rb")
X = pickle.load(pickle_in)
y = np.array(y)

import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import pickle
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras.models import load_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Opening the files about data
X = pickle.load(open("X.pickle", "rb"))
y = pickle.load(open("y.pickle", "rb"))

# normalizing data (a pixel goes from 0 to 255)
X = X/255.0

model = Sequential()
# 3 convolutional layers
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))

# Compiling the model using some basic parameters
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
                optimizer="adam",
                metrics=["accuracy"])
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

y = np.array(y)

history = model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=4, validation_split=0.1)
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file :
    json_file.write(model_json)

model.save_weights("model.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")

model.save('CNN.model')

# Printing a graph showing the accuracy changes during the training phase
print(history.history.keys())
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
```

Comment: Could you please provide the full code and furthemore I think the error message "ValueError: in user code:" is truncated in your post, something coming after the ":" ?

Comment: Sorry, it got cut off. I just updated it

Comment: There is something missing in your image preprocessing when loading the image, compared to the setup of your model, I guess. To track it down it would be good to have the full code.

Comment: Ok, Ill add it. Give me two minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just forgot to apply your def prepare(file).

Can you try

```
model.predict(prepare(image))
```

That is why there is a mismatch between RGB and exptected grayscale. Because the way you load it, it is RGB, because your prepare function is not applied. After applying, it should be a greyscale image and it should work.

Comment: And what is the result?

Answer (score 0):

So the error is quite clear.

```
expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape [None, 256, 256, 3]
```

The error says that the input channel which was supplied to the model is `3` due to `RGB` image but your model expects an image with channel `1`.

This means that your model is expecting a `grayscale` image and you are supplying an `RGB` image while predicting.

You should supply an image that has `[None, 256, 256, 1]` where `None` stands for `batch_size`.

Could you confirm this by adding your model code?

**UPDATE:**

You just updated your question so here I can see that you are training your model with grayscale images.

```
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
```

But I think while `predicting` you are calling with an RGB image.

Comment: No, this is not correct, as this is done in def prepare(file).

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.

Comment: This was the actual problem, you are right with the function call but that does not make my answer wrong.

Comment: Well ok, but it was misleading / not the problem. No offense, good that you're here!